# COUNTIFS with possibility of Fuzzy Match on one of the Criteria. Possible?

Tags: vba, excel

I've gotten myself into quite the mathematical "pretzel" and not sure how to get out of it.

I have a huge workbook that contains UPC codes in column D and Prices in column J.  I use the following VBA code within a larger macro to count the number of matching prices within all instances of the same UPC.  So basically, it's a FOR EACH unique product, COUNT the number of identical prices.

```
For R = 2 To UBound(Arr, 1)

    'Count the number of matching prices for each unique UPC
    Cells(R, 18) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Columns(4), Cells(R, 4), Columns(10), Cells(R, 10))

Next R
```

The Excel formula equivalent, if it would be easier to envision, is:  `=COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,J:J,J2)`

And now to my problem.  I need to also find/count prices for the same product that are within +/- 10% of the price being compared (the J2 part of the formula).

So basically, for a $1.00 product, any price between $.90 and $1.10 should be counted.

Is this even possible or am I just going about it all wrong?

EDIT: Contextual FYI - this is a workbook of 4,000+ unique UPCs over 30,000+ rows if that makes any differences in the best approach you would recommend for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula equivalent would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,J:J,">="& 0.9*J2,J:J, "<=" & 1.1*J2)
```

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Thank you so much.  This is perfect!!!  Just when I think I'm getting pretty good at this Excel/VBA thing, I learn something new.  I had no idea you could include those types of "strings" within formula conditions.  Your formula worked like a charm both within Excel and within my columns/cells VBA code.  Once again, THANK YOU!